# Is it possible to use the ML Kit SDK on Wear OS?

Tags: wear-os, firebase-mlkit

I am wondering if anyone knows if it is *possible* to use the ML Kit SDK on Wear OS devices? I know Wear OS is based on Android, and I've seen references online to Firebase notifications working on Wear OS.

I have googled combinations of the terms "ML Kit", "Firebase ML Kit" and "Wear OS" but not found any definitive answers.

I don't have code on hand, but I am wondering would it even be possible to import/use the SDK on Wear OS apps in the first place.

Expected results would be being able to instantiate and use some of the machine learning models from the ML Kit API on a Wear OS watch.

Battery usage and efficiency are secondary at the moment, I'm just wondering if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tied it but I think it is possible. In the end, the Andorid Wear 2.0 (WearOS) is just another regular Android and it supplies direct internet access from the device.

I was able to succesfully use RenderScript on Wear devices but on the other hand I've faced an issue that Google Awareness API was not available on Wear. THis seem not to be the expected state. 
Probably in the end you will need to do feasibility study on your own.
You can try to use some android MLKit sample and simply run it on Wear device.